# `conda list` show I have installed the package but I cannot import it

Tags: python

I have install the package using setup.py.

`conda list` shows I have the package installed. But when I tried to import it in Python, it said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'john_tools'`

steps:

1. pip install ./john_tools
2. conda list --> `john-tools                0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi`
3. from john_tools.strategy_analysis import dpd
4. import error

Here is my folder organization:
[image]

One strange thing is that the package name is `john-tools` but I expect it to be `john_tools`.

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
   name='johntools',
   version='0.1.0',
   author='John Chan | making difficult live easier',
   author_email='',
   packages=find_packages(),
   description='',
   install_requires=[
       "pandas",
   ],
)
```

This is the files inside Lib/site-packages:
[image]

I have also tried `__import__("john-tools")`. But not working

Comment: try without dashes and underscores in the name

Comment: After the `pip install`, look in the conda environments's `Lib/site-packages` folder to see what your `setup.py` did. Are the modules actually installed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `__init__.py` instead of `__inti__.py`?

Comment: @Dr.V attached the image.

Comment: In the direct_url.json: {"dir_info": {}, "url": "file:///G:/My%21Drive/Documents/Codes/id-cl/johntools"}

I am thinking whether that's a problem?

Comment: From the `setup.py`, I suspect you got a module called `strategy_analysis` installed. `setup.py` doesn't see `john_tools`. Can you `import strategy_analysis`? Did you correct the name of the `__init__.py` file? The `dist_info` doesn't tell much here, there should be a module folder under `site_packages` (just the module name).

Comment: @Dr.V import strategy_analysis works!